# Working with lists or someting similar to DataSet

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have two tables, let's call them Table1 and Table2. 
I have a variable named: `role`

Now I need to do a select statement from `Table1` (which can return several rows):

```
SELECT roles INTO role FROM TABLE1
```

And then I need to insert the `role` in Table2

```
INSERT INTO Table2(RELATION_ID, ROLES) VALUES (maxID+1, role);
```

Now my problem is that, the first select statement returns more than 1 row, and so I cannot put the value in the `role` variable. So I need something like an ArrayList or DataSet to put the values in, since I need to do a loop over these values, and insert them in another table. How do I use a list and iterate over it in SQL (Oracle).

Below you will see my code, simplified a bit, so that it is only my issue that is in focus. Of course the code will not compile, just trying to make clear what I need. Thanks.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "myProcedure"(eventID IN NUMBER)
    IS

    roleNumber NUMBER;
    maxID NUMBER;

    BEGIN
        SELECT roles FROM TABLE1;
        SELECT MAX(RELATION_ID) INTO maxID FROM SOMEOTHERTABLE;

    IF maxID IS NULL
     THEN
      maxID := 0;
    END IF;

    FOR counter IN theListThatINeed    
        INSERT INTO Table2(RELATION_ID, ROLES) VALUES (maxID+1, roleAtCounter);
    END IF;

    END "myProcedure"
```

Comment: if you use a sequence and a trigger to auto increment your RELATION_ID, the solution will be very easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a collection and get your job done. See below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myProcedure (eventID IN NUMBER)
IS
   ID_max   NUMBER;

   CURSOR cur
   IS
      SELECT roles FROM TABLE1;

   TYPE x IS TABLE OF cur%ROWTYPE
      INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

   var      x;
BEGIN
   OPEN CUR;

   FETCH cur BULK COLLECT INTO var;

   CLOSE cur;

   SELECT MAX (RELATION_ID) INTO ID_max FROM SOMEOTHERTABLE;

   IF ID_max IS NULL
   THEN
      ID_max := 0;
   END IF;

   FOR i IN 1 .. var.COUNT
   LOOP
      INSERT INTO Table2 (RELATION_ID, ROLES)
           VALUES ( (ID_max + i), var(i).roles);
   END LOOP;

   COMMIT;
END myProcedure;
```

Answer (score 2):

In this situation I would use just a single SQL Statement.  No need to context switch back and forth between the SQL engine and another language, and definitely no need to process something like this 1 row at a time!

```
INSERT INTO Table2(RELATION_ID, ROLES)
SELECT (SELECT NVL(MAX(RELATION_ID),0) FROM SOMEOTHERTABLE)+rownum, roles
FROM table1;
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the NVL( ) function.
Why do you ad the '+rownum', I don't follow?

Comment: rownum is a pseudocolumn that Oracle automatically adds as a number from 1 to however many rows you have.  So for the first row, this adds 1, second it adds 2, etc. to mimic your looping over the resultset and adding 1 to your variable each time.  More info can be found at: http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/ROWNUM-Pseudocolumn.htm#SQLRF00255

Comment: Thanks, I'll definately tak a look. I have yet much to learn about SQL. So if you leave out the '+rownum', will you get an error, or maybe inconsistency in your data?

Comment: The +rownum is what makes each row increment by 1.  If you took that off, every row would have the same value.  If relation_id had a unique constraint on it, it would give an error on the Insert.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not exactly you're asking about but solution for your problem is:

```
create sequence seqid start with 1 increment by 1;
INSERT INTO Table2(RELATION_ID, ROLES) 
  select seqid.nextval, role from table1;
```

If some other process can also insert to `table2` and you really need `max(id)` you can go with:

```
  with maxid as (select max(id) mid from table2)
  INSERT INTO Table2(RELATION_ID, ROLES) 
      select mid+rownum, role from table1, maxid;
```